# How to interaget my Unity android build package to another Android application?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I need to know how to integrate My Unity Build Android package to Another Android Application Any possible.

Then I need to know. can I build unity android SDK type any possible?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to integrate Unity game inside a normal android app.
To do this, you need to export to Android Studio.

First you need to open "Build Settings". You can open it from `File/Build Settings` menu.

[image: Build Settings Menu]

In build settings, you need to make sure you have selected Android as build platform. Then select `Gradle` as `Build System` and check `Export Project`:
[image: Build Settings]

Now hit `Export`.

Unity will export an Android project for you that you can open in Android Studio.